# How Mount EBS volume to ubuntu machine running outside Amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

Is it possible to mount EBS volume to locally running ubuntu?

[image]

Comment: No its not possible. But you could use S3 for that, which would not be same as using EBS, but it often is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Amazon EBS volume can only be mounted to an Amazon EC2 instance.